# Subjunctive with antes

Tags: subjuntivo

I recently heard a native speaker say

> "Te hubieras ido antes."

I was confused because it seems to be describing an event that occurred in the past, so it would be a completed action, so I assumed it would be in the indicative. My question is why was the subjunctive used here.

Comment: What is the complete context of the sentence?  There are quite a few ways in which those words could be used, but each has a different rationale so it's hard to explain without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in Spanish a subjective tense known as the **Pretérito Pluscuamperfecto del Subjuntivo** because it is not objective, but used in a hypothetical situation.

This can be used with the Past Perfect Subjetive or with the Conditional Perfect in English.

**e.g.**

> If I were you, I would have gone before.
> Si yo fuera tu, yo me hubiera ido antes. or also..
> Si fuera tu, ya me hubiera ido. (abbr)

**Conversation**

> Person 1: I've been waiting for her for 3 hours.
> Person 2: For three hours? You are crazy man! **You should have gone before.**
>
> Persona 1: He estado esperando por ella por 3 horas.
> Persona 2: ¿Por tres horas? ¡Estás loco! **Te hubieras ido antes.**

That's a hypothetical situation because, in fact, the first person stayed there for 3 hours, while the second person is giving advice based on something that has already happened in the past.

Answer (score 1):

These expressions are very used in Spanish language.
Of course, this could've been written as *te hubieses ido antes*, which means the same.

Now, as for Maximus examples, there are other ways to express the Past Perfect Subjunctive or Conditional Perfect Sentences:

> If I were you: si yo *fuese* tú.
>
> I would have gone: me *habría* ido.

Now, the same stands for *you should have gone*, which is *deberías haberte ido*.
If we want to say *te hubieras ido antes*, we put *you would've gone before.*

Answer (score 1):

To get a feeling of the tense, think either "desire" or "defeat".

If the thing is desired, we express our longing with the subjunctive.

> If I had wings, I would fly: Si tuviese alas, volaría.

If the situation is in the past, it often speaks about lost opportunity:

> If only I had known... : Si tan sólo lo hubiera sabido...

It is a tricky verbal form.